# How to create a service in powershell to execute .exe?

Tags: windows, powershell, service

I have powershell script. I need to run it as a service. I try this way to make it as a service.

```
Start-Process -FilePath C:\Users\xx\Downloads\nssm-2.24\win32\nssm.exe -ArgumentList 'install AgentService "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "-command "& { . D:\SERVICE\Script.ps1}"" ' -NoNewWindow
```

Then I open run.exe and type services.msc. The service exist. And I try to start it. It show like this picture.[image]

But I see the powershell script is not running. Because in my powershell script I use infinity loop to do some process, like copy and rename file. But It does not work.
Anyone can give me idea plese. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A ordinary EXE executable, by default, is not ready to be run as a Windows Service.

A service process needs to register with the Service Control Manager on startup and listen for commands from the SCM.  All the details you need are here:

C++: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/services

C# and .NET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/

However, if it helps, there are pre-built services that will launch and manage the process lifetime of any ordinary EXE.  Google for `run any windows exe as a service`.  One that I've personally used before is SrvStart.

Comment: Im not familiar with C++ and C#.

Comment: I try this way `$Function1 = @"
function myService() {
    New-Service -Name 'MyService' -BinaryPathName 'D:\Desember\EXE\Capturing.exe -k netsvcs'
}
"@
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -Wait -ArgumentList '-Command',"$Function1;myService;pause"`